# Mass Type Conversion in R

Tags: r, type-conversion

Instead of manually writing each one of these columns out in R how do I do a mass conversion of the entire sheet from integer to character?

```
Post <- mutate(Post, SurveyID_2 = as.character(SurveyID_2),
               P_Income_2 = as.character(P_Income_2),
               P_Education_2 = as.character(P_Education_2),
               Employ_1_2 = as.character(Employ_1_2),
               Employ_2_2 = as.character(Employ_2_2),
               Employ_3_2 = as.character(Employ_3_2),
               Employ_4_2 = as.character(Employ_4_2),
               Employ_5_2 = as.character(Employ_5_2),
               Employ_6_2 = as.character(Employ_6_2),
               Employ_7_2 = as.character(Employ_7_2),
               Benefit_1_2 = as.character(Benefit_1_2),
               Benefit_2_2 = as.character(Benefit_2_2),
               Benefit_3_2 = as.character(Benefit_3_2),
               Benefit_4_2 = as.character(Benefit_4_2),
               Benefit_5_2 = as.character(Benefit_5_2),
               Benefit_6_2 = as.character(Benefit_6_2),
               Provide_1_2 = as.character(Provide_1_2),
               Provide_2_2 = as.character(Provide_2_2),
               Provide_3_2 = as.character(Provide_3_2),
               Provide_4_2 = as.character(Provide_4_2))
```

Comment: Use `Post[] <- lapply(Post, as.character)`

Comment: Or `Post %>% mutate(across(everything(), as.character))`

Comment: Those are both pretty fast suggestions, but @akrun's is 20 times faster than the other one, which is typical of base versus tidyverse timings.